# How to convert json readble format

Tags: json, json.net

My current json readable format in file is .
 `{"delete" : {
        "_index" : "production",
        "_type" : "listings",
        "_id" : "f170321064",
        "_version" : 6,
        "result" : "deleted",
        "_shards" : {
          "total" : 1,
          "successful" : 1,
          "failed" : 0
        },
        "_seq_no" : 175987,
        "_primary_term" : 1,
        "status" : 200
      }
  }`

How to convert like below

```
   {"delete" : {"_index" : "production-cire","_type" : "listings","_id" : "424-l-81694-f1703210641700147","_version" : 6,"result" : "deleted","_shards" : {"total" : 1,"successful" : 1,"failed" : 0},"_seq_no" : 175987,"_primary_term" : 1,"status" : 200}}
```

Comment: Is this a C# question or something else?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what language you are using but I think this will work for you.

`let str = JSON.stringify({you_json})`

Comment: i am writing the response in output file using Curl .
{curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -XPOST "http://172.20.1.63:9200/production/listings/_bulk?pretty" --data-binary "@JSON.txt"  -o Response.json}

Comment: Could you try to remove `pretty` and see?

Answer (score 0):

if  using java or android:

The string exactly as you wrote it, I'm not sure you can turn it into JSON. but if you change it a bit like what follows it gives what you want:

```
    String str="{" +
            "delete : { " +
            "_index : production, " +
            "_type : listings, " +
            "_id : f170321064, " +
            "_version : 6, " +
            "result : deleted, " +
            "_shards : { " +
            "total : 1, " +
            "successful : 1, " +
            "failed : 0" +
            "}, " +
            "_seq_no : 175987, " +
            "_primary_term : 1, " +
            "status : 200" +
            "}" +
            "}";
    JSONObject obj= null;
    try {
        obj = new JSONObject(str);
        System.out.println(obj.toString());
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

see the output:

```
{"delete":{"_index":"production","_type":"listings","_id":"f170321064","_version":6,"result":"deleted","_shards":{"total":1,"successful":1,"failed":0},"_seq_no":175987,"_primary_term":1,"status":200}}
```